# How to start apache drill embedded inside my java application

Tags: java, apache-drill

I want my client to be able to do simple query on json file using SqL . i found one of the easiest solution is to use apache drill.

One of simplest api what i would like to give is for client to use the API and internally the system should be able to start the drill embedded by itself without client starting their own embedded drill

```
SqlLine.main(new String[]{"-d","drilldriver","-u","jdbc:drill:zk=local"};

//my query using select statement -- SELECT * FROM cp.`employee.json` LIMIT 1;
```

the drill can start properly but when i execute the query via JDBC driver it complain it cant connect to localhost:31010

I believe i need to put something in classpath so it can host / open up the rpc / jersey server also in this port as i have seen if i run via command line sqlline.bat -u jdbc:drill:zk=local.

Any idea ?